# faster multi-column partial string recognition loop in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, grepl

I want to create a fast function that returns true or false if a character string contained within one column the same as one of my columns.  The true or false is to be registered within the individually named columns.  Below is an example of the data structure:

```
df = data.frame(Authors, A1, A2 [... all the way A63])
# Example of "Authors" column row values: ("A1, A12, A50")
# All other columns equal: NA
# Note: "Authors" has millions of rows.
```

I have a nested loop that recognizes an author's name "A1" from a column that often contains multiple such "Authors" / "df[,1]" (Example: "A1, A12, A50"), and returns "True" into a column named after the specific author ("A12") if the author's name is contained within this string (alternatively, "False").  Here is a slow nested loop that achieves the intended result:

```
for (i in 2:length(df)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
df[j,i]= ifelse(grepl(df[j,1],colnames(df[i])), TRUE, FALSE)}}
# Intended result df[2,2] = "True" if df[2,1] = ("A1, A2, A50"), otherwise "False".
```

The above works, but it is excruciatingly slow. I have millions of rows. 
Any pointers as to how I might speed this up?

**Edit: Below is what my dataframe looks like via dput:**

```
structure(list(Authurs = c("A. Trevor Thrall", "A. Trevor Thrall", 
"A. Trevor Thrall", "A. Trevor Thrall, Benjamin H. Friedman", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Benjamin H. Friedman", "A. Trevor Thrall, Benjamin H. Friedman, Christopher A. Preble, Peter Russo", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", "A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", "A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", "A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", "A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey"), `Jeffrey A. Singer` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    `Caroline Dorminey` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `Eric Gomez` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `John Samples` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), `Emma Ashford` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm sure there will be a faster method. Your description of the file is somewhat confusing. As is almost always the case when people use ellipses in there pseudocode). It would be helpful if you could run `dput(df[1:15,1:6])` and use the edit feature to paste the text output into your question.

Comment: Sure.  Added accordingly.

Comment: Is the author column always consistently formatted with a standard comma delimiter?

Comment: Yes - they are always delimited by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your object fragment so that it would ahve some actual hits.

```
df <- 
structure(list(Authors = c("A. Trevor Thrall", "A. Trevor Thrall", 
"A. Trevor Thrall", "A. Trevor Thrall, Benjamin H. Friedman", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Benjamin H. Friedman", "A. Trevor Thrall, Benjamin H. Friedman, Christopher A. Preble, Peter Russo", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", "A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", "A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", "A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", "A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey", 
"A. Trevor Thrall, Caroline Dorminey"), `A. Trevor Thrall` = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), `Benjamin H. Friedman` = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), `Christopher A. Preble` = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), `Peter Russo` = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), `Caroline Dorminey` = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now that there are some hits, try this:

```
df[-1] <- lapply(names(df[-1]), function(nm) grepl(nm, df[[1]]))
```

It loops through each of the non-"Authors" column names and sets TRUE or FALSE depending on whether there is a grepl-hit in the 'Authors' column. I think that is what you asked for and I assure you it will be much faster than the dual nested loop with `ifelse` testing. What I have eliminated is the inner loop and replaced it with a vectorized operation. The outer loop is essentially unchanged since `lapply` and `sapply` are both really equivalent to a for-loop in terms of speed. It's the algorithm inside the loop that matters.

Comment: Wow, this is infinitely faster!  Thank you so much.